# HTML form to trigger both php and javascript when submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple html form with just a box for the user to enter their email address.

When the "submit" button is pressed I want the email address submitted to be:

(a) emailed to me

(b) automatically added to a Google form

I can do both of these individually. I can perform (a) using:

```
<form id="input-form" action="email.php" method="POST">
```

where "email.php" is:

```
<?php
    mail('me@gmail.com', $_POST['email'], "Add to Mailing List");
    header('Location: https://my_website.com/thanks.html');
?>
```

and I do (b) using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>                           

<script>                                                                                                           
  $('#input-form').on('submit',function(){                                                                       
    var inputq1 = encodeURIComponent($('#email').val());                                                       
    var q1ID = "entry.1047793221";                                                                             
    var baseURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpFLSe7dz1sfyEigQF3QGkTfKCieaqb8OgXoGzLOZPmhn6TvjqFg/formResponse?';                                                                                                    
    var submitURL = (baseURL + q1ID + "=" + inputq1);                                                          
    console.log(submitURL);                                                                                    
    $(this)[0].action=submitURL;                                                                               
    $('#input-feedback').text('Thank You!');                                                                   
            location.replace("https://my_website.com/thanks.html")                                     
});                                                                                                            
</script>
```

When I comment out the javascript, the submitted information is emailed to me as desired and the user is directed to my "thank you" page. But when I **include** the javascript, now the email doesn't arrive, but the email address that they entered is instead added to the Google form. So the Google form works part works, but it seems to override the sending of the email to myself.

Additionally, when the javascript is included the user no longer is redirected to my "thank you" page. Instead they are just directed to the Google form thank you page:

[image]

How can I get both (a) and (b) to happen after submission please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to to activate your email.php script:

```
<script> 
$('#input-form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this stops the form submit

    var inputq1 = encodeURIComponent($('#email').val());                                                       
    var q1ID = "entry.1047793221";                                                                             
    var baseURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpFLSe7dz1sfyEigQF3QGkTfKCieaqb8OgXoGzLOZPmhn6TvjqFg/formResponse?';                                                                                                    
    var submitURL = (baseURL + q1ID + "=" + inputq1);                                                          
    console.log(submitURL);                                                                                    
    $(this)[0].action=submitURL;

   var data = {
        // fill with form input values
        email: $('#email').val(),
   };


    // send ajax request to send your email
    $.ajax({
        url: '/email.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function( response ) {
            response = JSON.parse( response );
            // check if email is sent successfuly and respond appropriately
            if (response.status == 'success') {
                $('#input-feedback').text('Thank You!');                                                                   
                location.replace("https://my_website.com/thanks.html")  
            } else {
                $('#input-feedback').text('Ooops! Something went wrong.');  
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log( xhr.responseText );
        }
    });
 }); 
 </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$response = [
    'status' => 'error',
];

// validate input values
if (empty($_POST['email'])) { // this is the most basic validation
    echo json_encode($response); exit();
}

// check if mail was sent successfuly
if( mail('me@gmail.com', $_POST['email'], "Add to Mailing List") ) {
     $response['status'] = 'success';
     echo json_encode($response); exit();
}
// if email failed to send
echo json_encode($response); exit();
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to be dumb, but does the top section have to be within <script></script> tags?

Comment: @user1551817 Yes, all javascript/jquery code has to be either in <script> tags or in a file that has extension .js

Comment: So, I do get the email, but instead of going to the thank you page, I get a white page with "{"status":"success"}" and also the message doesn't seem to get sent to my Google form.

Comment: Is email.php separate script from the one you have you html and javacript in?

Comment: Yes. My html and javascript is in index.html and the php is in email.php

Comment: IT seems that your form is still being submitted by form action atribute inestead of by Ajax. Check of everything is ok with e.preventDefault